# Blender rendering issue

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm new to blender, just trying to learn lighting and got some issue - I've got some strange rendering on the walls and the cup. This is render when I have more than 1 area lamp:

[image]

But if lamp is only one, it's okay:

[image]

I can't google this issue, because I dont even know how to call this effect :)
Please, help me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using 'blender-render' or 'Cycles'?

Comment: I'm using Cycles